# Getting an error certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying the "Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric (multiple organizations)" tutorial and I am stuck at the composer network ping stuff. The ping commands fails giving this error "Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".

I am trying with "tls disabled" flag for peers and orderer. Also I am trying a multivm setup where orderer, org1 and org2 are running on separate vms. And I am using composer version 0.16.2 and hyperledger fabric version 1.0.4.

Any idea on this?

Comment: if tls really is disabled - have you got http:// and gprc:// in your connection.json files instead of https:// and grcps:// ?
There is also a thread on Rocket Chat where using a hostname has helped:  https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=wPAmysbEPoaEswpWi

Comment: Yes I had changed to http and grpc after disabling tls. Also I am already using host names in my json files.

Comment: The error is saying that you tried to connect to the peer's event hub using an identity that has been signed by some unknown authority. Are you sure the MSP for the peer has been setup correctly ? Have you checked that the peer has successfully joined the channel ? I assume you are using an identity you have obtained from a fabric-ca server, so have you checked the fabric-ca server has been setup correctly ? 
Finally check that you aren't trying to connect to a peers event url in a different organisation to the user you are trying to connect with. You won't have authority for obvious reasons

Comment: Thanks @david_k, I was able to sort out, my ca certificate had an issue.

Comment: Could you share how you fixed the issue?