# Hyperledger Composer: Error trying to ping business network: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Receiving error when Fabric CA Server starts (ca.org1.example.com)

This is the error:

```
Could not load TLS certificate with BCCSP: Could not find matching private key for SKI: CSP:500 - Failed getting key for SKI [[74 227 52 30 73 220 158 98 138 158 61 209 206 89 246 99 232 211 108 174 62 7 117 225 123 88 119 70 196 195 234 44]]
```

Receiving error for the command:

`composer network ping -c alice@tutorial-network
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Command failed`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FSGC.png)

Environment:
Using Fabric Samples First Network environment. org1 with 2 peers (peer 0 & 1), org2 with 2 peers (peer 0 & 1), 1 orderer, 2 ca servers (ca0 & ca1). Docker Yaml file attached.

Answer (score 0):

It could not find the private key for the public key for alice@tutorial-network.  Are you creating a custom network (same machine (localhost) or different machines?)  or following the 0.16.x tutorial here where the steps are prescriptive? -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

see also answer here [Getting an error certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186336/getting-an-error-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority?rq=1) this may be similar to what you're seeing, in particular the CA certificate.